# How do I change my "no data" values to get "true" values in raster calculator in Qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, nodata

I have two rasters and I want to subtract the values from one of the layers.
The first raster is a altitude raster and the second raster is depth values for a lake. 
I would like to subtract the depth values to get the altitude of the bedrock under the lake. 
When I do this in the raster calculator (raster 1 - raster 2) the resulting raster is all wrong and have extreme negative values (-1,7 x10^35). 
It has been pointed out to me that the "no data" values for one of the rasters are within the size of my  negative output.

How do I change the "no data" values to get the result I'm after?

Comment: Did you try your subtraction "by hand" on a few pixels, to compare with the raster calculator results? And can you put in your question the *exact* formula you used?

Comment: are the areas outside your lake set to a NODATA value (say -1.7e35)?

Comment: iant: How do I see if that is the case? When the rasters was cut they came out a little bit different. Is there a way to cut them so that the cells get exactly the same?

Comment: @Lark - look at the statistics of the raster in the properties window

Comment: @iant - there is no data below 1100 m in the histogram.

Comment: look at the General tab below Layer Source: there should be columns, rows, nodata value boxes

Comment: @iant- Oh...that one says -999
What can I do about that?